# How do I copy a hyperlink without the stuff past . html?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, links, greasemonkey

When shopping on certain sites like aliexpress there is a lot of extraneous junk past the .html at the end of the URL. What's an easy way to copy the link while omitting anything past that? Something like an extension, a greasemonkey script, or something else? I'm using firefox but a chrome solution would also be welcome.

Here's a sample URL:

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Starter-Kit-For-Arduino-UNO-R3-Upgraded-Version-Learning-Basic-Suite-For-Uno-R3-Board-Stepper/32696561124.html?ws_ab_test.... goes on awhile... &algo_pvid=5e586e79-51ab-466c-a97a-5c5ba94e5930

shorten to

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Starter-Kit-For-Arduino-UNO-R3-Upgraded-Version-Learning-Basic-Suite-For-Uno-R3-Board-Stepper/32696561124.html

Comment: Open Notepad (Windows) or GEdit (Linux), paste there and copy what you want again. It won't extend the copying process by a few seconds. That's convenient enough.

Comment: Search for a clipboard manager that can change the text automatically, maybe one with  regex or similar

Comment: Chrome Browser doesnt do this with their own links for search results. Havent found a solution that works for Firefox in 2022: softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/84141/30586

Answer (score 2):

I often just do it backwards in the address field. Put the cursor at the end of the ".html", and click and drag to the left to highlight the rest of the URL. That way you don't have to be as precise while dragging.

Comment: Instead of clicking and dragging, typing SHIFT+HOME and then CTRL+X would be quicker,